# Update field values from module settings

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I made a module for show several products whose id come from a new table.

The table´s (ps_inicialmod) structure is:

- id_desta
- id_prod (id_product for the relationship)
- mod (Values - 1: "Featured Prod", 2: "Product Offer", 3 "Featured Collection").

The table data is:

```
   id_desta              id_prod              mod

     1                     2                   1
     2                     7                   1
     3                     5                   2
     4                    11                   2
     5                    23                   2
     6                    20                   3
```

The module has 3 functions:

- obtenerDestacados(): Searchs for mod 1, gets the products data and pass it to the tpl.
- obtenerOfertas(): Searchs for mod 2, gets the products data and pass it to the tpl.
- obtenerColeccion(): Searchs for mod 3, gets the products data and pass it to the tpl.

So far, so good.

But i don´t know how to change the id_prod field of each row from settings page.

Settings.tpl:

```
{$message}
<fieldset>
<legend>Configuraci&oacute;n</legend>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        Productos destacados:

     </p>

     <p>
         <label for="???">Prod. Destacado 1:</label>

         <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
     </p>

      <p>
         <label for="???">Prod. Destacado 1:</label>

         <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
     </p>



        <p>
        Productos en oferta:

        </p>

        <p>
           <label for="???">Prod. Oferta 1:</label>

           <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
        </p>

        <p>
           <label for="???">Prod. Oferta 1:</label>

           <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
        </p>

        <p>
           <label for="???">Prod. Oferta 1:</label>

           <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
        </p>

        <p>
        Colecci&oacute;n destacada:

        </p>

        <p>
           <label for="???">Colec. Destacada 1:</label>
           <input id="???" name="???" type="text" style="width:20px !important;" value="{???}" />
       </p>


        <p>
        <br />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input id="submit_{$module_name}" name="submit_{$module_name}" type="submit" value="Guardar" class="button" />
</p>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple select dropdown for the product selection.

There you can list all the product and select is for the three conditions.

you have set the $products variable which contain product ids and names to the smarty.

```
{$message}
<fieldset>
<legend>Configuraci&oacute;n</legend>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        Productos destacados:

     </p>

     <p>

<select name="mod1[]" multiple>
{foreach from=$products item=product}
    <option value="{$product.id_product}">{$product.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
     </p>


        <p>
        Productos en oferta:

        </p>

        <p>
    <select name="mod2[]" multiple>
{foreach from=$products item=product}
    <option value="{$product.id_product}">{$product.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
        </p>

       <p>
        Colecci&oacute;n destacada:

        </p>

            <select name="mod3[]" multiple>
{foreach from=$products item=product}
    <option value="{$product.id_product}">{$product.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>


        <p>
        <br />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input id="submit_{$module_name}" name="submit_{$module_name}" type="submit" value="Guardar" class="button" />
</p>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

after this form submission you will get an array of product ids in each mod. so you can process it.